# Retrieval of one column of an array outputs a shape of (1, 2) instead of (2,1). What am I missing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `z = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])` which has the shape (2, 3).
Within one column there is one x and one y value. I want to retrieve the values of one column `print(z[:, 2]`. However, instead of outputting a (2,1) shape, I get a (1,2) shape.

The output I got:

```
[3 6]
```

The output I expect:

```
[[3]
 [6]]
```

The thing is, I want to add `z[:, 2]` to another variable of the shape (2,1). What am I missing? And how can I achieve my goal? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Let me try again. `I get a (1,2) shape.` No, you don't - you get a `(2,)` shape (i.e., 1-dimensional). That is because using an integer in the slice *reduces the dimensions* of the slice - in the same way that if you index into an ordinary Python list, you get *one of the elements*, instead of a list with one element in it. The problem is solved *in the same way*: slice that dimension, rather than indexing it. The necessary slice is formed *in the same way*: as a `x:x+1` range. (There are other ways as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slice with a 2D selector:

```
z[:, [2]]
```

output:

```
array([[3],
       [6]])
```